# Restore db from sql file

Tags: mysql

I am tring import data from sql file using command line like this:

mysys-12: mysql -u root -p my_db_t < my_db_t_2022_10_12.sql

but I got:

mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTIO

How can I import data? Should I add any params?

Comment: what is the content of your sql file ???

Comment: run Mysql console, connect to server, and run source commande : **source file.sql;**

Comment: Before.. I dump final DB to copy test version,  mysqldump -u root -p dbx12_final > my_db_t_2022_10_12.sql

Comment: what is the version MySQL do you use ???

Comment: Well, when I put mysql -v I got the same error: mysql -v sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'.

Comment: I see two config file: mysql.config.d (Server confguration) and mysql.cnf (Client configuration).  Mayby, I should delete "sql-mode" from client configuration... ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the content in the sql file conflicts with the constraint of sql_mode. There are two methods. The first method is to modify the content of the file to meet the constraint of sql_mode. The second method is to set SQL _ mode ='' in mysql. Then import the data and change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I removed sql-mode from client configuration, file: etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

Server configuration - No change